# How would you make this kind of paint animation over a text?

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation, svg

Try to load this website, and hover the text:

http://www.guillaumetomasi.com/

the effect is pretty nice. A sort of dynamic painting over it. How would you do this? Some starting point suggestions? Plugin?

I guess it's plain HTML5/Canvas and SVG, isn't it?

Comment: This one is made with canvas/svg...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect page, you would find the source: http://www.pixijs.com/
It all depends on Canvas obviously. Pixijs is a huge library, found on GitHub.

https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js

Answer (score 0):

He's definitely using canvas, you can see that if you inspect the page code.
He's probably using the text as a mask for the images that change based on what group of words are being hovered over. And on hover he applies a blur effect to the text which again acts as the mask for the image.

Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_globalcompositeoperation.asp for the "mask" effect.